# Node.js 0.8.2 on CloudFoundry Micro edition 1.2

Tags: cloud-foundry

The documentation for CloudFoundry indicates that Node.js version 0.8.2 is supported. However, when I run "vmc runtimes" against my local micro edition, it only lists node and node06 (not node08)

I'm running 0.8.2 locally on my box -- how can I upgrade Micro edition so that it also has 0.8.2 installed?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the best place to ask support questions like this, you would be better off asking the makers of CloudFoundry.

Comment: Actually StackOverflow is the primary place where we answer CloudFoundry questions :-)

Answer (score 3):

Micro Cloud Foundry 1.2 was released before Node.js 0.8.2 support was added. MCF currently cannot be upgraded to support it. However, a new MCF version is planned for the very near future which will bring parity to all the feature on CloudFoundry.com. We also plan a faster release cadence of MCF so it doesn't fall behind on features.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely trivial to patch MCF 1.2 to add node 0.8, you'd need to install the relevant packages as well as add information to the Cloud Foundry manifest files to enable it to advertise the node08 runtime.

However, the next Micro Cloud Foundry release should be available pretty soon so if you can hold on just a little longer, we should have some good news for you :-)

Out of interest, what application are you looking to build / run that requires 0.8.x?

Answer (score 0):

Micro Cloud Foundry has just been updated to be in sync with the codebase on github so it now supports Node.js 0.8.2. Read the announcement here: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/11/08/new-release-of-micro-cloud-foundry/